# How can I move an object bullet towards a target?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to shoot a bullet prefab towards a target. I want it to just go towards the target current location. If the target changes position the bullets should still go to the old target position, instead of the current position the target is at.

```
Vector2 pos;
            
pos.x = tracker.transform.position.x;
pos.y = tracker.transform.position.y;
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

The above code just makes the bullet prefab track the object even though the object moves. If an object is at 0,0 then the bullet should go towards it but if the player changes its position to 1,1 the bullet should still go to 0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply cache the previous position that the object was at and `MoveTowards` that instead of the player as that will go to the current position. Instead of continually updating the `pos.x` and `pos.y`, set them initially when the bullet is fired and not again.

```
private Vector2 targetPos;
private bool bulletInited = false;
private float bulletSpeed;

public void InitBulletTarget(Vector2 target)
{
    bulletInited = true;
    targetPos = target;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(bulletInited)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

When you `Instantiate` your bullet prefab, you will want to call the `InitBulletPosition` and send in the proper position which would be the `tracker.transform.position`.

An example would be

```
private void SpawnBullet()
{
    // spawn the two bullets
    YourBulletScript bullet1 = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation).GetComponent<YourBulletScript>();
    YourBulletScript bullet2 = Instantiate(bullet, firePoint2.position, firePoint2.rotation).GetComponent<YourBulletScript>();

    // set their target position to move towards
    bullet1.InitBulletTarget(tracker.transform.position);
    bullet2.InitBulletTarget(tracker.transform.position);
}
```

Comment: Hi bro i will try this but i am using this function to instantiate  void shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        Instantiate(bullet, firePoint2.position, firePoint2.rotation);
    }

Comment: @MalikNouman Those are fine. The attached code you posted in your question is in a script on your `bullet` prefab right? I updated the code snippet to use your instantiation code.

Comment: Yeah bro they are on prefab. You helped me earlier once too Thank you so much.

Comment: @MalikNouman Glad to help again :) If you found either of my answers solved your problem, you can close the question and accept my answer by clicking on the arrow to the left of my answer. If you need more help, I can update the answer I gave.

Comment: It worked. it wasn't working as there was no speed but I changed and it worked . I love you and God bless you.

Comment: @MalikNouman Oh that might have been because I left the speed variable as default, so it was set to 0.0f, but it looks like you figured that out. Good luck with your game!